# Listen for Document And Media view/download events

Tags: audit, liferay-7

I want my code to be called everytime someone **views** or **downloads** anything in Document And Media:

View:
[image]
Download:
[image]

The content URLs of the view and download (to which the HTTP response is an actual preview image or PDF itself being transfered) are respectively:

```
http://localhost:8080/documents/20143/0/invoice_ABC_2017.10.27.pdf/c44fd479-331b-f393-7879-973c5cecf086?version=1.0&previewFileIndex=1
http://localhost:8080/documents/20143/0/invoice_ABC_2017.10.27.pdf/c44fd479-331b-f393-7879-973c5cecf086?download=true
```

The responses to both requests seems to be built by [WebServerServlet.sendFile](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/webserver/WebServerServlet.java#L943), a part of Liferay which is unfortunately not an OSGi module.

My first instinct would have been to implement [ModelListener](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/model/ModelListener.html), but it only has methods for creation/update/deletion events, nothing for read events.

How to intercept these events in Liferay? (7 EE DXP)

Answer (score 0):

Model listeners are connected to the CRUD operation that can happen on an entity.

You could attach your self to the download action. Have a look here https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/converting-strutsactionwrappers-to-mvccommands

Answer (score 0):

## Preview

Preview (in the sense of the preview page being displayed by any user) can be intercepted by deploying a component that takes the place of the `MVCRenderCommand.class` service. To do that, copy [Liferay's ViewFileEntryMVCRenderCommand.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/collaboration/document-library/document-library-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/document/library/web/internal/portlet/action/ViewFileEntryMVCRenderCommand.java) and add your code in the `render` method:

```
@Component(
        property = {
                "service.ranking:Integer=100",
                "javax.portlet.name=" + DLPortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY,
                "javax.portlet.name=" + DLPortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY_ADMIN,
                "javax.portlet.name=" + DLPortletKeys.MEDIA_GALLERY_DISPLAY,
                "mvc.command.name=/document_library/view_file_entry"
        },
        service = MVCRenderCommand.class
)
public class MyViewFileEntryMVCRenderCommand implements MVCRenderCommand {

    @Override
    public String render(
            RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
        throws PortletException {

        DoMyAuditThing();

        [...]
   }

   [...]
}
```

## Download

Download (in the sense of a Document and Media being actually downloaded) can be intercepted by creating a Servlet Filter (copied from the [Liferay plugin samples](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/hooks/sample-servlet-filter-hook)) with this `liferay-hook.xml` configuration:

(UPDATE: Just after writing this code I realized that there is now a [better way to write Servlet Filters](http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-dxp-filter-tutorial/))

```
<hook>
        <servlet-filter>
                <servlet-filter-name>Sample Filter</servlet-filter-name>
                <servlet-filter-impl>com.liferay.sampleservletfilter.hook.filter.SampleFilter</servlet-filter-impl>
                <init-param>
                        <param-name>hello</param-name>
                        <param-value>world</param-value>
                </init-param>
        </servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-mapping>
                <servlet-filter-name>Sample Filter</servlet-filter-name>
                <before-filter>SSO Open SSO Filter</before-filter>
                <url-pattern>/documents/*</url-pattern>
                <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
                <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        </servlet-filter-mapping>
</hook>
```

Note the `<url-pattern>/documents/*</url-pattern>` part.

The Filter class:

```
public class SampleFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(
                        ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                        FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

                String uri = (String)servletRequest.getAttribute(
                        WebKeys.INVOKER_FILTER_URI);

                // Extract information
                String[] tokens = uri.split("/");
                if(tokens.length < 6) {
                        System.out.println("Failed to parse download URI (Too few slashes): " + uri);
                        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                        return;
                }
                long groupId;
                try {
                        groupId = Long.parseLong(tokens[2]);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("Failed to parse download URI (Group not a number): " + uri);
                        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                        return;
                }
                String uuid = tokens[5];
                System.out.println("group:" + groupId + " uuid:" + uuid);
                DLFileEntry fileEntry = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.fetchDLFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId(uuid, groupId);

                // Send it to your audit
                [...]

                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
}
```

A problem is that it seems to also catch unnecessary events when showing the Document and Media page... I investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the Service Wrapper and in particular the getFile method. This method it’s called when the user request the download of the file.